# How to convert raw JSON response data into an ArrayList of model objects using Spring for Android?

Tags: android, json, spring, rest, restlet

I'm learning spring for android with androidannotations and I'm having trouble casting JSON data received via HTTP Get to my model objects.

I have the following code:

```
myRestClient.getRestTemplate().getMessageConverters().add(new GsonHttpMessageConverter());
ArrayList liveMatches = myRestClient.getLiveMatchesForUser((long) user_id);
```

This response is actually just a JSON representation of a list of `Match` objects.

How can I convert this raw JSON response into an `ArrayList<Match>` object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me.

I created a simple class which was just a wrapper of an ArrayList data structure.

Something like:

```
public class MatchesListWrapper {

public ArrayList<Match> matches;

public MatchesListWrapper(ArrayList<Match> matches) {
    this.matches = matches;
}

public ArrayList<Match> getMatches() {
    return matches;
}

public void setMatches(ArrayList<Match> matches) {
    this.matches = matches;
}
```

}